# how can I conditionally display image if one is attached to channel entry

Tags: channel-entries, conditionals

I have an image that is an optional channel field, and I've got it hard coded into the template.  If someone doesn't attach an image, there is an empty image box on the page for that entry.  How can I tell EE to check for an image, and if its not there, just load the rest of the page normally?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this should work:

In this example I use three custom fields: `article_image`, `image_description` and `class`.

```
{if article_image != ""}
   <img src="{article_image}" alt="{image_description}" title="{image_description}" class="{class}" />
{/if}
```

You can also use the shorthand version of the above code like so "{if custom_field}content here{/if}". This shortens up the code a bit.

Comment: There is a `{}` button in the editor, or simply indent it by four spaces (we use markdown formatting)